# How to set SEO attributes in aurelia

Tags: javascript, seo, meta, aurelia

Here is the main problem I'm having. I want to set social share buttons to an Aurelia application page.

In general, I have to set three meta tags objects:

```
head title
[property="og:image"]
[property="og:description"]
```

What is the best way to handle this in Aurelia? Is it possible to do this using the Route object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by just writing a service that modifies the head content directly using the DOM API. There is no way to nicely bind to the head content as a view.

Here is a gist of my implementation
https://gist.github.com/dpix/6f508727b9d03d692d0659eb1776ad85

Comment: Nice approach, I implemented it in our project. However, Facebook does not seem to run JS so even though our pages set `og` "tags" Facebook won't read them.

Comment: Most crawlers will not unfortunately. This requires doing prerendering of your client side app on the server web crawlers. Check-out https://prerender.io

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the settings property on a route itself? This is an object where you can specify data for a particular route, I personally use it to specify icons for menus generated using Aurelia, but it can be used for anything.

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Test Route';

    config.map([
        {
            route: ['', 'welcome'],
            name: 'welcome',
            moduleId: './welcome',
            title: 'Welcome',
            settings: {
                image: '/images/someimage.png',
                description: 'This is my social share description for this route.'
            }
        }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}
```

Now to access the settings object, inside of your route viewmodel you will define a callback method called `activate` this method receives 3 parameters. The first one is any route parameters and the second is the route object itself for the current route.

```
export class MyViewModel {
    image = null;
    description = null;     

    activate(params, routeMap) {
        if (routeMap.settings) {
            this.image = routeMap.settings.image;
            this.description = routeMap.settings.description;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now inside of your view template HTML, you can do this:**

`${image}` and `${description}` to get the above values that you set inside of your viewmodel taken directly from the current route.

Comment: The main problem, that attributes usual have a place inside `<head>`. That broke me :(